# How do I fix the TypeScript error: TS2234: All declarations of an interface must have identical type parameters

Tags: typescript

In typescript v0.9.5 this code compiled.

```
interface Array {
    indexOfField : (propertyName: string, value: any) => number;
 }
```

After upgrading to typescript 1.0, I get the following error:

(2,11): error TS2234: All declarations of an interface must have identical type parameters.

Line number 2:11 is the keyword Array.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The other definition of `Array` is `Array<T>` (with a type parameter) in `lib.d.ts`. You need to declare yours as:

```
interface Array<T> {
    indexOfField : (propertyName: string, value: any) => number;
}
```

in order to have the same number of type parameters.