# TypeScript typings broken (error TS2687): All declarations of 'iterator' must have identical modifiers

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having an issue getting my typings correctly after I've added the router package to my Angular application (which required an upgrade of Core, Common, Compiler etc.).

Googling ob that specific error code led me to a number of problems, the main resolution for which is removing *node_modules* and *typings* and recreating them. I've done so but experience the same misbehavior.

On SO, there's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307510/how-do-i-fix-the-typescript-error-ts2234-all-declarations-of-an-interface-must) but it's old, relates to a different versions of most of the packages and I hardly see how it relates to my problem.

Frankly, I'm a bit lost because I have no idea how to troubleshoot it at all. Below is my *tsconfig.json* if it helps to spot something odd.

**edit**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const distribution = path.resolve(__dirname, "distribution");
const application = path.resolve(__dirname, "source/application");
const resources = path.resolve(__dirname, "source/resources");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./source/application/main.ts",
  output: {
    path: distribution,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "raw-loader", include: [resources] },
      { test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/, loaders: ["raw-loader", "sass-loader"] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw-loader", include: [application] },
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader", include: [application] },
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules", application],
    extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
  },

  performance: {},
  devtool: "source-map",
  context: __dirname,
  target: "web",
  externals: [],
  stats: {},

  devServer: {
    contentBase: distribution,
    port: 3002
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./source/index.html" }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "./source/resources", to: "resources" }])
  ]
}
```

Comment: Add the Path in External Web Tools C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: @VenkateswaranR Where exact do I set it, please? And to what do I set it?

Comment: In Visual Studio Toolbar Tools-->Options-->Projects&Solutions--->External Web Tools and C:\Program Files\nodejs and set it as first

Comment: @VenkateswaranR Hmmm... I'm on VS Code, i.e. not Visual Studio at all...

Comment: Are you using webpack, can you mention typescript version

Comment: @VenkateswaranR Sure. Webpack 2.0, TS 2.2. Building with Node 7.0 under NPM 3.10

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack.common.js remove the line  debug=true, and change the below code

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
]},
plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
```

Comment: For Typescript 2 we can either use typings or we can include under developerdependencies like '@types/node','@types/jasmine','@types/core-js'

Comment: I was hoping not to pollute the forum with my *webfig.js* but it appears that I'll have to. Please see the edit. It's practically the same as yours. And I'm not clear on where in it that the source of the error originates.